# What does ::1 mean in apache logs?

Tags: windows, apache, logging, xampp, localhost

I looked into XAMPP's apache's **access.log** file:

```
::1 - - [29/Aug/2014:19:18:35 +0700] "GET /xampp/splash.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1325 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
::1 - - [29/Aug/2014:19:18:35 +0700] "GET /xampp/xampp.css HTTP/1.1" 200 4178 "http://localhost/xampp/splash.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
::1 - - [29/Aug/2014:19:18:35 +0700] "GET /xampp/img/blank.gif HTTP/1.1" 200 43 "http://localhost/xampp/splash.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
::1 - - [29/Aug/2014:19:18:35 +0700] "GET /xampp/img/xampp-logo.jpg HTTP/1.1" 200 19738 "http://localhost/xampp/splash.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
```

What does `::1` mean? I believe it means localhost because the XAMPP is used only for local testing in my PC. However I also found these lines that shows 127.0.0.1.

```
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Aug/2014:01:04:14 +0700] "GET /xampp/splash.php HTTP/1.1" 200 1325 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [30/Aug/2014:01:04:14 +0700] "GET /xampp/xampp.css HTTP/1.1" 200 4178 "http://127.0.0.1/xampp/splash.php" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0"
```

So why there are `::1` and what is the difference with 127.0.0.1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

::1 is the localhost address in IPv6. While 127.0.0.1 is your localhost address in IPv4. In other words it's you.

Comment: why sometimes showed up as ::1 and the other times showed up as 127.0.0.1 ?

Comment: Not sure why it changes possible your network card got an IPv6 address from your gateway. I believe that Windows prefer IPv6 if you are offline.

Comment: I'm looking my log now, the apache logs put ::1 if I access it from browser. But I remember I was testing android apps using genymotion's android emulator which connect to the XAMPP's apache's localhost at that day, probably that's what made the 127.0.0.1 showed in the log file.

Comment: That is a good explanation that emulators commonly use IPv4 only.

Comment: and why it is in access log?

Comment: Well your browser or any other http client from your computer accessed that resource via IPv6.